# C++ Regex: Matching words after hyphens

Tags: c++, regex

I am a bit new to C++ regex and trying to make a regex work. Basically, I want to match `"the pickle"` in the following sentence:

```
I      pick picked   --  the pickle
```

To implement this, I am using the following regex --> `std::regex reg3 ("(--)[\\s]*.+")`

However,my output is the following:

```
--  the pickle
```

My desired output is:

```
the pickle
```

Any idea, how I should modify my regular expression to not pick up the hyphens (--) and the spaces?

Comment: You captured the hyphens. Capture the rest. `std::regex reg3(R"(--\s*(.+))")`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Is there any documentation on using R in the regex?

Comment: @arpita_taurus -- the `R` is a convenience that isn't specific to regular expressions. It stands for **raw** literal. You can write `"\\s"`, as you did, to put the characters backslash and s into a string literal, or you can write `R("\s")` (note: only one backslash) to do the same thing, without having to deal with the compiler's notion of escape sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the capture groups `()` to delineate submatches:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string txt = "I pick picked -- the pickle";

    std::regex re(R"(--\s*(.+))");
    std::smatch m;

    if (std::regex_search(txt, m, re)) {
        std::cout << "Full match: " << m.str() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Groups: " << m.size() << "\n";
        std::cout << "First paren capture group: " << m[1] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3cf266a47fab8c4)**

```
Full match: -- the pickle
Groups: 2
First paren capture group: the pickle
```